# Examples of Elementor Pro form to webhook integration

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I am using elementor wordpress plugin. I have made a form using elementor pro plugin. I want to get data when form is submitted and send an external api call with form data. I studied elementor documentation but did not found clear code sample. Is there is a way to send form data to external api.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After doing lot of research on elementor plugin. I got the solution. I add following hook in my custom plugin and it works.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_elementor_pro_forms_send_form', [ $this, 'ajax_send_form' ] );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_elementor_pro_forms_send_form', [ $this, 'ajax_send_form' ] );

function ajax_send_form() {  
// form processing code here
}
```

Comment: Does this work? What is the webhook URL you have used?